# Download Google Docs Spreadsheet via PHP

Tags: php, csv, google-sheets

I'm trying to download and parse a google spreadsheet directly via PHP.
Do i need to download the exported CSV file from google docs a different way?

```
$csv = file_get_contents('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/KEY/export?format=csv');
print_r($csv);
```

I tried it with file too:

```
$csv = file('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/KEY/export?format=csv');
```

And with cURL

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/KEY/export?format=csv"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.example.org/yay.htm");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MozillaXYZ/1.0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

$csv = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($csv);
```

When i call the URL from a browser i get a nice tiny CSV file. This way i get the source of the google docs website.

Comment: Those URLs presumably expect you to be authenticated. https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads

Comment: you are right. I set it to public and now i can parse it. man i should go home now. thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to download the csv as UTF-8 format?